# How can I figure out the indexPath of a cell I'm not pushing using didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've got a `UITableView` with custom cells inside, which trigger a detail view when a `UIButton` in them is tapped. Tapping the cell itself does not trigger the segue, meaning `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is never called.

Before implementing this, I was using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to set up the object being passed to the detail view via its indexPath in my `NSFetchedResultsController`'s `fetchedObjects` array. Since I'm now not using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, I can't access the indexPath there.

I've already tried using the `tag` of the button, but since it can't store an `indexPath`, this doesn't work when I call `objectAtIndexPath` before the segue. I've also tried accessing the button's `superview` to get its `indexPath`, but that didn't work either, was always nil.

How else can I know which `UIButton` was pushed, so that I can pass the correct object to my detail controller?

**Edit:** I thought of the idea of adding a `UIButton` category that adds an `indexPath` property, but I'm having trouble doing this since it expects a method to go along with it. Would this approach work?

Comment: Is your `UITableView` have more than one section ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the superview of the button (or the superview of superview of the button) to get the Cell and get the indexpath of the cell from tableview

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by adding the following to the method called when I tap the button:

```
UIView *contentView = (UIView *)[sender superview];
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[contentView superview];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell: cell];
_quote = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: indexPath];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"ViewDetail" sender: nil];
```